# php fsockopen return error 0 when connect to a mail server

Tags: php, sockets, email

I have trouble sending notification emails to the mail server. The piece of code handle that is:

```
 $this->smtpSocket =   $this->smtpSocket = fsockopen(($this->secure == 'ssl' ? 'ssl://' : 'tcp://') . $this->smtpHost, $this->smtpPort, $errno, $errstr, 60);
```

The value of `errno`, `errstr` and `$this->smtpSocket`  are 0 , `NULL`and `FALSE` respectively.

The php manual say:

> If the value returned in errno is 0 and the function returned FALSE,
>   it is an indication that the error occurred before the connect() call.
>   This is most likely due to a problem initializing the socket.

But that doesn't help me much fix this :(

Here's my checklist:

- The `smtpHost` , `smtpPort`  and the protocol is correct. It can be use for thunderbird to send/receive mails on that computer.
- The above point mean the network is not blocked on necessary port to the mail server.  However, the computer is blocked for internet access. I wonder that could have any effects, since the mail server uses GlobalSign certificate?

A few more info: I use Vertrigo 246_x64 bundle with PHP 5.6.30

Comment: any updates on this !!!

Comment: Hi @RupeshPatel; please check the firewall, somehow a few necessary ports (465...) are not enough; I must set the firewall allow any connections to make it works :(

Comment: Ok, so for me it was issue about ssl certificate, when fsockopen response code is 0, it means, it has not reached to the server at all. so the problem will be on connection code or other configurations. I have not installed certificate and was trying to connect through ssl protocol so it was returning with 0.